# "Non-existing" FCM messages with stats in dashboard

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

In FCM, I can see the stats dashboard for messages however there's no message/campaign created, why? Permission? What are we sending to the users?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmsl4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK191.png)

Expect to see the messages and previews. Thanks for the answers.